# fopen changes variable value in C

Tags: c, cs50

I'm taking the EDx CS50 class from Harvard to learn C and I noticed a strange behavior of my code in one of the problem sets (I already came up with a solution that worked, but I want to understand why the original one doesn't). The idea of the assignment is to check a file where references to jpeg files have been deleted, and thus recover photos from memory.

The issue I have is with the `foundJPEG` boolean below. My original idea was to set it to false until the first photo was found and after that start writing the individual files (they were supposed to be in continuous blocks of memory). The first time a jpeg header was found, a new write file would be generated and the information copied there until a new jpeg was found. Additionally, the `foundJPEG` variable would become `true`. Originally I only had this declaration under the else clause of the  `if(foundJPEG)` block of code, but after running it I noticed that every time the `fopen` function was called, the variable went back to `false`. Hence, I just added a new `foundJPEG = true;` statement after opening a new file, even in the case when the variable was already changed to true.

What I want to know is why the boolean is becoming false every time `fopen` is called. In particular, since C gives so much control about memory allocation, I was wondering if it was because it was somehow being overwritten whenever I open a file or because of some scope issue. I guess this is probably a rookie mistake but I thought maybe someone could help me understand this better so that I don't compound mistakes when writing larger applications. Thank you very much!

```
/*
* recover.c
*
* Computer Science 50
* Problem Set 4
*
* Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int k = 0;
    bool foundJPEG = false;
    char title[7];
    FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
    FILE* img;

    BYTE buf[512];
    int size = sizeof(buf);
    while(fread(&buf, size, 1, file) == 1) {
        if(buf[0] == 0xff && buf[1] == 0xd8 && buf[2] == 0xff && buf[3]  >= 0xe0 && buf[3] <= 0xef) {
            if(foundJPEG) {
                fclose(img);
                k++;
                sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", k);
                img = fopen(title, "wb");
                foundJPEG = true;
            }
            else {
                sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", k);
                img = fopen(title, "wb");
                foundJPEG = true;
            }


        }
        if(foundJPEG) {
            fwrite(&buf, size, 1, img);
        }

    }

    fclose(img);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you compress your problem into a sentence or two? Reading novels isn't too fun.

Comment: I think you may have undefined behaviour when first calling fclose(img) when img has never been defined. Plus you have a block of code strictly identical in if and else foundJPEG test.

Comment: @self Sorry, it's my first time writing a question here. Basically, I want to know why in that block of code the fopen function changes the value of the foundJPEG boolean.

Comment: Any reason you obfuscate `uint8_t` as `BYTE`? 1) all-uppercase should be used for macros/enum-constants only. 2) A byte does not necessarily have 8 bits. 3) Using the standard type makes your code clear to anyone without knowing the declaration of `BYTE`. 4) `typedef` only to include semantics into names.

Comment: @Olaf Not really, another part of the assignment used it like that and I was trying to use it in my own code to make sure I understood how it worked (the BYTE had to do with the bitmap infoheader structure suggested in the  Microsoft website). Thanks anyway, jcoder already pointed out what was causing undefined behavior so I will just read on that to make sure I don't make this type of newbie mistake again :).

Comment: Microsoft does not have a standard compliant C compiler. So it is a bad reference. `BYTE` or `WORD` are MS-specific relics, but today just bad style. Anyway, they should be already defined in some header, don't hand-craft them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two instances of indefined behavour in your code.

```
fclose(img);
```

You are calling this with img uninitialized

```
char title[7];          
sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", k);
```

The sprintf will write 8 characters 3+4 + null terminator to a 7 byte buffer which will overwrite something else on your stack.

It's likely one of these causes your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, I forgot about the null terminator in the title array :(. About the img thing I'm guessing I should initialize those to NULL from now on.